# bitcoinaverage.com price precision

Tags: exchange-rate, historical-trade-data

i noticed that from the 13th of feb 2015 the bitcoin price becomes a lot more "noisy" on [bitcoinaverage.com](https://bitcoinaverage.com/charts#USD-averages-false):

[image: price noise]

does anybody know whether this is actually due to bitcoin price movements becoming more rapid, or whether its just that bitcoinaverage.com increased their sampling frequency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the issue is that they don't have the data. I think they're just showing the data at a lower sampling rate.

This chart draws data from three locations:

- https://api.bitcoinaverage.com/history/USD/per_minute_24h_sliding_window.csv
  Updates once per minute, but only has 24 hours of data.
- https://api.bitcoinaverage.com/history/USD/per_hour_monthly_sliding_window.csv
  Updates once per hour, but only has a month of data.
- https://api.bitcoinaverage.com/history/USD/per_day_all_time_history.csv
  Updates once per day, but has all data.

Note how the data that goes back further is less precise.

Comment: thanks. that is actually noticeable now you mention it - the last hour is more precise than the time before it.